# Validate Image on Web Page Using Geb and Spock

Tags: automated-tests, spock, specifications, geb

I'm new to using geb and spock, but I'm trying to validate an image displayed on a webpage when I only have the view-source of the code. Any advice is appreciated! I modeled this code off of a link test I previously wrote, so I'm certain I'm missing something. An example of my page file is:

```
// code not included where I have defined the url/etc. Below is content

someImage { $("img", file: "image-logo.png") }
```

And an example of my spec page is:

```
def "Valid image"() {
        given: "an image checker"
        to SomePage
        when:
        someImage.hover()
        then:
        verifyAt()
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'validate' in this context, the link/it's checksum/...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to validate that the image is present on the webpage. I was thinking I could do so by checking if it's file name was present on the source page, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach to handle this.

Comment: You should locate the image via and id/css selector, and then verify the `src` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate that the image styling is set to `displayed`, any content that has the css property `display: none` cannot be interacted with via the webdriver API.

I have experienced some issues with using the `isDisplayed` method on navigator objects in Geb so I would do the following:

Where you define the page content add a method for checking the content can be interacted with (therefore is set to displayed):

```
someImage { $("img", file: "image-logo.png") }

Boolean contentDisplayed(Navigator content) {
    content
}
```

Then your test will look like this:

```
def "Valid image"() {
    given: "an image checker"
    to SomePage
    when:
    someImage.hover()
    then:
    contentDisplayed(someImage)
```

its worth noting here that simply accessing the `.hover` method here you are validating that the image is `displayed` as far as the css is concerned. So you could simplify the test to:

```
def "Valid image"() {
    when: "an image checker"
    to SomePage
    then:
    contentDisplayed(someImage)
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!